# Flyway maven plugin setting

Tags: maven, spring-boot, flyway

My Pom.xml setting for maven plugin is

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>

            <!-- Note that we're executing the Flyway
                 plugin in the "generate-sources" phase -->
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>migrate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <!-- Note that we need to prefix the db/migration
                 path with filesystem: to prevent Flyway
                 from looking for our migration scripts
                 only on the classpath -->
            <configuration>
                <baselineOnMigrate>true</baselineOnMigrate>
                <url>databaseUrl</url>
                <user>username</user>
                <password>password</password>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>schema_name</schema>
                </schemas>
                <locations>
                    <location>filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration</location>
                </locations>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

While running mvn clean install I am getting below error

> Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb:flyway-maven-plugin:3.0:migrate
>   (default) on project Test: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException:
>   Found non-empty schema "schema_name" without metadata table! Use 
>   init() or set initOnMigrate to true to initialize the metadata table.
>   -> [Help 1]

What am I missing here? I tried some changes like adding baselineOnMigrate but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue, I had to upgrade the version of flyway plugin. I was following an old blog to setup it and in that blog the version of this plugin is 3.0, that is quite old. I upgraded it with latest one. Then after it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

try to update your Flyway version

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
     <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>6.5.6</version>
</plugin>`
```

hope this help. get more info here https://flywaydb.org/documentation/maven/